# PHP-based Crossword Creator code

Tags: php, crossword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Script for generating Crossword game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955033/php-script-for-generating-crossword-game)

Does anyone know any PHP-based simple Crossword Creator API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's not a programming question

Comment: try to google for `PHP-based simple Crossword Creator` I am sure you will find one.

Comment: @Adam: Welcome to StackOverflow, btw! Please, do not take offence from the comments above. The community here is in charge of deciding which quesions to allow on this site, and questions formulated in a single sentence have a relatively high probability of getting closed. I hope Gordon's answer is helpful, but if it is not, do not hestitate to edit your question, adding more information on the specific problem you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googling for crossword + php](http://www.google.de/search?q=Crossword+php) yielded

- [PHP Crossword](http://phpcrossword.sourceforge.net/) is PHP and MySQL based crossword generator.

as the first link.

If that one doesn't fulfill your needs, then please provide more information about what you are looking for in a Crossword Creator/Framework/API.

Comment: I was about to post the same link, but then I also noticed [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955033/php-script-for-generating-crossword-game) in the Google results. You might to manually migrate your answer there, in the case that this one gets closed :)

Comment: @Jørn the duplicate is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943113/algorithm-to-generate-a-crossword and both are much more generic in question, so I don't think the answer would fit there.

Comment: I am not sure I agree. I think this question is a duplicate of 955033 (which explicitly asks for a PHP script), while I consider 943113 is a seperate, more conceptual, question. Hence, I find that you answer would be appropriate for 955033, but I neither have intention nor instruments to force you to cross-post it :)

Comment: @Jørn am too lazy :) feel free to add the link yourself to where you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the help, that's what i need.

I don't know if my question is an duplicate or not. But i know if I come to stackoverflow, i will be getting answers! Thanks SOF. ;)

@Jørn for your kind words :).