# An Algorithm/PHP code for word finding game

Tags: php, algorithm

Well, I recently have been trying to come with code to create matrix in which word hunting can be done. I want the user to initialise rows, columns and of course give the words, it is too difficult to create such code/algorithm as the words can be placed vertically, horizontally or diagonally. I also tried google for such algorithms but without any luck. So, if anyone has an algorthm in mind or has written such PHP code, itll be really great if I can see that.

Thanks in Advance,

Nalin Bhardwaj

Comment: you didn't think googling 'word search puzzle algorithm' would come up with at least 1 suitable answer? including an answer on SO ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332652/a-fast-algorithm-for-creating-a-puzzle or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943113/algorithm-to-generate-a-crossword

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry , I posted this question here, as suggested by one of the users, I googled a few different things online an dhave found a ruby file which has been built for the same purpose. And , if anybody would like to access it, they may check it out online at http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/298382 . And, now I have decided to use this algorithm itself to create such a PHP file. Thank you everybody, for suggestions