# Optimal word placement in a two-dimensional array according to special rules

Tags: algorithm

Objective: Develop code that can place a set of words within a two-dimensional array. The words can be arranged horizontally, vertically, diagonally from left to right, or diagonally from right to left. Words can also be reversed if necessary.

Input:

1. Size of the two-dimensional array (e.g., 8x8).
2. A collection of words (e.g., `"DATE", "DAY", "FIRST", "YEAR", "SECOND", "YOU", "ZONE"`).

Example of full input:

```py
OptimalWordPlacement(SizeOfTwoDimensionalArray=[8, 8],
                     collectionOfWords=["DATE", "DAY", "FIRST", "YEAR", "SECOND", "YOU", "ZONE"])
```

Rules:

Words must not exceed the dimensions of the array.

[image]

Letters can intersect, but only once per cell. For example, ‘DATE’ arranged vertically and `DAY` arranged horizontally can intersect at the letter `A`. However, `DATE` vertically, `DAY` horizontally, and `YEAR` diagonally (in any direction) cannot intersect at the letter `A` because that would result in more than one intersection at a single cell in the array.

[image]

Any unused cells should be set to `_`.

[image: Example of a correct array]

Output: The program should provide all possible two-dimensional arrays with the optimal placement for words, occupying minimal space within the array.

Note: Optimal placement refers to the arrangement that allows the maximum number of words to be placed within the array while adhering to the rules. If there are multiple optimal placements, the program should return all of them. (In other words, it should return all possible solutions from the best to the worst)

Could you help me come up with an algorithm to solve this problem?

---

So far, I have attempted to implement a solution (that is, I have not yet managed to solve the problem completely). This solution finds only one case also bugs occur:

```py
def place_words(board, words):
    def is_valid(board, word, x, y, dx, dy):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            nx, ny = x + i * dx, y + i * dy
            if nx < 0 or nx >= len(board) or ny < 0 or ny >= len(board[0]):
                return False
            if board[nx][ny] not in (0, word[i]):
                return False
        return True

    def place_word(board, word, x, y, dx, dy):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            nx, ny = x + i * dx, y + i * dy
            board[nx][ny] = word[i]

    def remove_word(board, word, x, y, dx, dy):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            nx, ny = x + i * dx, y + i * dy
            board[nx][ny] = 0

    def backtrack(board, words, index, tried_positions):
        if index == len(words):
            return True
        word = words[index]
        for x in range(len(board)):
            for y in range(len(board[0])):
                for dx, dy in ((0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, -1)):
                    if (word, x, y, dx, dy) not in tried_positions and is_valid(board, word, x, y, dx, dy):
                        place_word(board, word, x, y, dx, dy)
                        tried_positions.add((word, x, y, dx, dy))
                        if backtrack(board, words, index + 1, tried_positions):
                            return True
                        remove_word(board, word, x, y, dx, dy)
        return False

    if not words:
        return board
    tried_positions = set()
    if not backtrack(board, words, 0, tried_positions):
        print("No solution found")
    return board

i = 6
j = 6
board = [[0]*i for _ in range(j)]
words = ['DATE', 'DAY', 'FIRST', 'YEAR', 'SECOND', 'YOU', 'ZONE']


result = place_words(board, words)
for row_of_result in result:
    row_of_result = ['_' if x == 0 else x for x in row_of_result]
    print(row_of_result)
```

Output:

```
['D', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'F', 'Y']
['A', 'Y', 'O', 'U', 'I', 'E']
['Y', 'Z', '_', '_', 'R', 'A']
['_', 'O', '_', '_', 'S', 'R']
['_', 'N', '_', '_', 'T', '_']
['S', 'E', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'D']
```

This particular example has been solved correctly, but I need all possible solutions

Comment: As far as finding all solutions, isn't that just a matter of recording the solution when found (in a list, say) and then continuing on as if you hadn't found a solution instead of returning?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156911/generate-a-crossword-from-given-words-maximizing-intersections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943113/algorithm-to-generate-a-crossword/

Answer (score 1):

I made the following code:

```py
def can_place(board, row, col, word, vertical=False, diagonal_lr=False, diagonal_rl=False):
    if vertical:
        if row + len(word) > len(board):
            return False
        return all(board[row+i][col] in ('_', word[i]) for i in range(len(word)))
    elif diagonal_lr:
        if row + len(word) > len(board) or col + len(word) > len(board[0]):
            return False
        return all(board[row+i][col+i] in ('_', word[i]) for i in range(len(word)))
    elif diagonal_rl:
        if row + len(word) > len(board) or col - len(word) < -1:
            return False
        return all(board[row+i][col-i] in ('_', word[i]) for i in range(len(word)))
    else:
        if col + len(word) > len(board[0]):
            return False
        return all(board[row][col+i] in ('_', word[i]) for i in range(len(word)))
    
def place_word(board, row, col, word, vertical=False, diagonal_lr=False, diagonal_rl=False):
    intersections = []
    if vertical:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if board[row+i][col] == word[i]:
                intersections.append((row+i, col))
            board[row+i][col] = word[i]
        return 'vertical', intersections
    elif diagonal_lr:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if board[row+i][col+i] == word[i]:
                intersections.append((row+i, col+i))
            board[row+i][col+i] = word[i]
        return 'diagonal from left to right', intersections
    elif diagonal_rl:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if board[row+i][col-i] == word[i]:
                intersections.append((row+i, col-i))
            board[row+i][col-i] = word[i]
        return 'diagonal from right to left', intersections
    else:
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if board[row][col+i] == word[i]:
                intersections.append((row, col+i))
            board[row][col+i] = word[i]
        return 'horizontal', intersections

def fill_board(board, words, placements=[], index=0):
    if index == len(words):
        return [(board, placements)]

    solutions = []
    word = words[index]
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[0])):
            for vertical, diagonal_lr, diagonal_rl in [(False, False, False), (True, False, False), (False, True, False), (False, False, True)]:
                if can_place(board, row, col, word, vertical, diagonal_lr, diagonal_rl):
                    new_board = [row.copy() for row in board]
                    placement, intersections = place_word(new_board, row, col, word, vertical, diagonal_lr, diagonal_rl)
                    solutions.extend(fill_board(new_board, words, placements + [(word, placement, intersections)], index+1))
                if can_place(board, row, col, word[::-1], vertical, diagonal_lr, diagonal_rl):
                    new_board = [row.copy() for row in board]
                    placement, intersections = place_word(new_board, row, col, word[::-1], vertical, diagonal_lr, diagonal_rl)
                    solutions.extend(fill_board(new_board, words, placements + [(word[::-1], placement + ' + reverse', intersections)], index+1))
    return solutions

board_size = 5
board = [['_']*board_size for _ in range(board_size)]
words_to_place = ['DATE', 'DAY', 'YEAR']

all_possible_boards = fill_board(board, words_to_place)
for i, (board, placements) in enumerate(all_possible_boards):
    print(f"Solution {i+1}:")
    for row in board:
        print(''.join(row))
    print("Placements:")
    for word, placement, intersections in placements:
        print(f"{word}: {placement}, intersections at {intersections}")
    print()
```

I use a backtracking algorithm to speed it up, but it still doesn't work perfectly when I enter large data. For instance, when I input a 8x8 grid and 8 words, it never completes.