# How to arrange a bunch of words so that the letter count is minimized?

Tags: algorithm

I'll start of with an example, to clarify what kind of algorithm I'm looking for:

For example, there are the words `one`, `two` and `three`. Those could be arranged like that:

```
three
w
one
```

or

```
  t
  h
t r
w e
one
```

More examples:

```
   t
eight
 t r
 w e
 one

eightwo
    h
    r
  one
    e

 n
eightwo
 n  h
 e  r
  one
    e

eightwo
    h
    r
  one
 nine
```

etc.

How could I achieve this algorithm, for getting the

a) the least character count?
b) tightest arrangement?
c) for any combination?

This is not homework nor a interview question, I'm trying to rebuild the QlockTwo with a slightly different design.

Comment: Could you define 'word count' formally? Or maybe give an examples where this is clearly different between examples

Comment: The word and letter counts are the same in both these examples.

Comment: What is `word count` ? `b) for any combination` is not making any sense. What is `QlockTwo`? And this sort of question is best suited for cs.stackexchange rather than SO as it doesn't involve any code.

Comment: Concerning "word count": I actually meant character count, sorry! I've also updated the question I think b) makes sense when you consider character count. QlockTwo can be found here: http://www.qlocktwo.com/. Should I just cross-post this to cs.se?

Comment: I found [this](http://tools.atozteacherstuff.com/word-search-maker/wordsearch.php), which looks almost like what I want. I'm really curious about the algorithm that's in use here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23435654/4465729